# How to generate CloudFormation code from Java?

Tags: java, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to write CloudFormation templates in Java code and generate `yaml` or `json` from them?

I spotted this [troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) tool that allows you to write Python code decribing the stack and generate CloudFormation code from it.

I'm looking for similar solution that would allow me to write code in Java instead. Is there any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to check out the new AWS CDK, it does exactly that.

> The AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK) is an open-source software development framework to define cloud infrastructure in code and provision it through AWS CloudFormation. ... currently available for Java, JavaScript, and TypeScript.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-cdk-developer-preview/

https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk

Comment: Unfortunately, it's so far from being usable to us, looking at their roadmap: https://github.com/orgs/aws/projects/7